# Python cant find environment

Tags: python, environment-variables, conda

I can't run my `main.py` file, because python can't find some specific modules. However, I created an environment with all the needed modules in conda and set that as my default python interpreter in pycharm.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
-----project
--------- src
------------environment.yml
------------main.py
----------venv
--------------include
--------------lib
--------------scripts
```

I am not sure about what there is inside the `venv` folder, but I know it was created when I created the conda environment from the `environment.yml` file.

Comment: I believe the venv folder is the virtual environment created by conda witth the dependencies you specified in your environment.yml.

Comment: This is what i think too. However, when I try to run my main, it says it cannot find keras. SO im not sure what to do about this.

Comment: Given that you are using PyCharm, I would recommend that you double check on the project level settings which interpreter you are using and the path. It might be that you are using your system's python path (and hence no keras package available) instead of the Conda one.

Comment: I agree with @goosfraba. Can you share some screenshots of your interpreter settings in PyCharm?

Comment: Also, how did you create the environment?

Comment: the environment was created with conda from the environment.yml file which specified all the needed libraries. Then, when it said no default interpreter found I selected the python one with the same name as the environment that was created from conda.